# Can't fade div with JavaScript calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want an div to fade back an forth, but cant get it to work with JS and jQuery!

This is my JS part:

```
function animateTxt() {
      $j("#addajaxmsg").fadeIn(2000).delay(6000).fadeOut(1500, function() {
        animateTxt();
      });
  }

  function ChangeSauce()
  {
    // document.getElementById('alertmsg').style.color = '#0000ff';
    document.AddForm.textareaadd.value='';
    animateTxt();



  }
```

And HTML part:

```
<button id="alertmsgdiv" onClick="AddAlert(document.getElementById('alertminput').value, document.getElementById('alertmsg').value, document.AddForm.sms.checked);ChangeSauce();" >Add</button>
<div id="addajaxmsg" style="display: none;">test</div>
```

As you can see, i "must" use "ChangeSauce", couse i load addAlert() witch post to alert.php

And why does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `#addajaxmsg` initially to `display: none`:

http://jsfiddle.net/6MTxT/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it in the question, it has display: none inside the style="" now

Comment: @Dennis: well, then there is an error somewhere else. See the example link, works fine.